# Unable to center footer in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

I am unable to center the footer on the page.  All content is centered on the page and set to 1280px, so it does not take up the entire width of the page.  The issue is that everything on the page is centered except the footer.  It is the correct width, but the footer is pushed hard left.  Any ideas what I am missing?

This is what the footer looks like currently:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/Style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="png" href="../Pictures/Icon.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="xxx">
    <meta name="keywords" content="xxx">
    <meta name="author" content="xxx">
    <title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>xxx</h1>
      <h2>xxx</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="xxx.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="xxx.html">Manage Income</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="xxx.html">Manage Bills</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="xxx.html">View Calendar</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a id="signout" href="SignOut.html">Signout</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pie"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
  <a id="contact" href="xxx.html">Contact Us</a>
</footer>
</html>


footer{
  display: block;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #B6B6B4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's almost impossible to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: see debugger if anything is overriding your css

Answer (score 0):

Your example code appears to align correctly for me.

Note that your width of `1280px` means that the text will be centered at exactly `640px` (half of `1280px`), and this is likely **outside of your viewport** at smaller widths, meaning it will **seem** as though your text is not central.

To remedy this, use a **percentage-based** width instead, such as `100%` to indicate that your footer should occupy the full width available:

```css
footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #B6B6B4;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  Test
</footer>
```

As you can see in the above example, the text is visible even though the viewport is narrow.

Note that it's also possible that your footer's CSS is being overridden by a selector with [**higher specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). You can use the [**F12 Debugger**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to ensure that your rules are being applied correctly.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try the debugger.  I thought that maybe something previous may be overwriting the selector, but I haven't been able to pin it down yet.  I appreciate the answer! I added an image of it.  Maybe you could take a look and see if you think that is what is occurring? Thanks either way!

Comment: Looking at your new code, I'm still unable to reproduce your problem. I still maintain that the problem is to do with your width; try using a `width` of `100%`, or if that doesn't work, a width of `100vw`. It's also possible that your text needs `margin: 0 auto` applied to it (for aligning a `block` rather than inline content). Other than that, start with my working example, and add your code onto it, **dividing and conquering** to identify the problem. If you still have issues, that will help you provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)